# How to get ThreeLetterISORegionName from RegionInfo in WP8 library

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

For some reason I can't get RegionInfo.ThreeLetterISORegionName in library that targeting WP8/WP8.1 - only 2-letter code.

Is there a simple way to get ThreeLetterISORegionName?

Comment: Only in Russia, the English version of that page doesn't promise WP8 support.  You know it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone Silverlight [RegionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.globalization.regioninfo(v=vs.105).aspx) does not provide a ThreeLeterISORegionName, only the [TwoLetterISORegionName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.globalization.regioninfo.twoletterisoregionname(v=vs.105).aspx) .

To get the three letter name you'll need to provide your own translation or call an external web service.